# Trouble creating my first association object: teachers in a school

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Would like to create a teacher, within a school in the web browser.  Unsure exactly what code I need to do this. Used scaffold to create school and controller and model to create teacher.  My goal is to be able to add teachers, after I create a school.

School model

```
    class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teachers
end
```

Teacher model

```
    class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
end
```

School controller

```
    class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_school, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /schools
  # GET /schools.json
  def index
    @schools = School.all
  end

  # GET /schools/1
  # GET /schools/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /schools/new
  def new
    @school = School.new
  end

  # GET /schools/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /schools
  # POST /schools.json
  def create
    @school = School.new(school_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @school.save
        format.html { redirect_to @school, notice: 'School was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @school }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @school.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /schools/1
  # PATCH/PUT /schools/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @school.update(school_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @school, notice: 'School was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @school }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @school.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /schools/1
  # DELETE /schools/1.json
  def destroy
    @school.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to schools_url, notice: 'School was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_school
      @school = School.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def school_params
      params.require(:school).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Teachers controller

```
    class TeachersController < ApplicationController
end
```

School/view/show

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @school.name %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_school_path(@school) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', schools_path %>
```

Comment: inye: I tried a couple of different things, but I'm having trouble connecting the dots on how to create a teacher in the school/show.  I'd like for the school user to be able to create teachers, once logged into the account.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this within either your school or teachers controller, you may want it in create, definitely in update. Assuming the school controller and that params includes a teachers name as :teacher_name.

```
def update
  @school.teachers = Teacher.new(school_params[:teacher_name])

  respond_to do |format|
    ... snip for brevity ...
  end
end
```

I am assuming your database tables are already set up using [migrations].[1](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Comment: thanks Matt.  I will give this a try.  As I mentioned in my reply above, I'd like for the school user, to be able to create teachers in their school.  Which means for now, I'm aiming to have the 'teachers create forms' visible in the school show.  The above code helps and I will try to get that work.

Answer (score 0):

From the Teacher Side:

In your Teacher new page (your form) you'll need to have a selection box with the schools the Teachers can belong to, those Schools will have as values their IDs (from the Database). The Teacher model will have school_id as one of its attributes and once you got to your rails console and type something like School.first.teachers you'll get a list of all the teachers in that school.

Comment: Thanks for your response rii.  I was able to successfully complete it the way you described.  My preference would be for the school user, to have the option to create teachers as part of the school and not the other way around.  Think of it like this:  You are an administrator at a school and after you login, would like to add the teachers to your school.  That is what I'm aiming to complete.  I could of been clearer in my original post.  Hope that makes sense.